# Insert single quote or double quote to the database with codeigntier

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, input, htmlspecialchars

When I load the data into the input box:

```
<input type="text" name='name' value='<?= ($activity->name); ?>' class="form-control">
```

if the data contain single quote, it will strip the later part of the string, because of the conflict of the symbol

So I fix it with

```
<input type="text" name='name' value='<?= htmlspecialchars($activity->name); ?>' class="form-control">
```

It works. The problem is , it is tedious to apply it into all input box, are there any workaround that apply globally, for codeigniter?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of globally changing codeigniter function, its better to change your code and save the name data by stripping all the unnecessary characters.

Comment: I would like to , but the user need to insert single quote and double quote

Comment: Hi Can you add the output you need and what output you get now

Comment: So if correct, your value has double quotes and is causing some form of conflict with your output?

Answer (score 3):

you can use both type of quote. there's no reason to use sinlge / double quote.

```
<input type='text' name='name' value='<?=($activity->name); ?>' class='form-control'>

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=($activity->name); ?>" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use form helper:

```
$data=array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'name' => 'name',
    'value' => set_value('name', $activity->name)
);
echo form_input($data);
```

Or if you don't want to escape anything

```
'value' => set_value('name', $activity->name, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't doble quote un the value?

```
<input type="text" name='name' value="<?=($activity->name); ?>" class="form-control">
```

There's no reason to use single quote...

When you save "name" in the DB, you can use addslahes($name) ...

Comment: thanks , the problem is , if the $activity->name contain double quote, then it is still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think for codeigniter use it's own syntax for input text box try this one,

```
<?php echo form_input(array("name" => "name", "class" => "form-control input-sm", "value" => $activity['name'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the `htmlspecialchars` in the class. Something like

```
class Activity{
   public $name = htmlspecialchars("value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Every question has a solution.**

I tired with assigning config and all what i can do. Finally find the best solution for you. Now you don't want to add  `htmlspecialchars()` for all the function. Just use below code.

> One more thing In CI there method call [`html_escape($var)`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/common_functions.html#html_escape) read about that too as well

---

### Changes

Go to **`system/core/input.php`**(I'm using CI 3 so go to line 254)

Change this

```
public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
{
    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
}
```

to  this

```
public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
{
    return htmlspecialchars ($this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean));
}
```

> In order to use this form method should be `method="post"`. and in controller you have to use `$this->input->post('');`. **`$_POST` will not work for yours**.

---

### Example - Code

**In view**(sample form)

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/form'); ?>
<h1>Create Contact Form Using CodeIgniter</h1>
    <?php echo form_label('Student Name :'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?>
    <?php echo form_label('Student Email :'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'demail', 'name' => 'demail')); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**In Controller**

```
echo $this->input->post('dname');
```

---

### Input & Output

**Input** is `This is some <b>bold</b> text.` which i took from [w3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)

[image: input]

**Output** is `This is some <b>bold</b> text.`

[image: Output]

---

### Check in

1. [GitHub](https://github.com/Abdulla-nilam/htmlspecialchars-to-input) (Recommended)

Comment: You should never be changing core files in Codeigniter.

Comment: @JimPannell post something when you know about it. There is ***no RULE to say do not change***. It's for newbies like you. If you want that as an example saying "we can do anything", then search **`CodeIgniter Error: variable references`** and check where we need to make the change KIDDO

Comment: The recommendation is that you EXTEND Codeigniter's core functionality - not hack the core files. Why? Because your changes could be overwritten when upgrading to a newer version of CI.
Instead what you can do is copy the input.php file, make the necessary changes and place it in your application/core/ folder, renaming it MY_Input.php. 
That way when you upgrade, your changes will be intact.

Comment: You still didn't get the point that says, "**There is no RULE for not to edit**."

Comment: That's right - it isn't a rule, but it is considered best practice. Everyone is free to do what they want at the end of the day.

Comment: Bro, there is no best practice in not editing core. Its also just a PHP file. If you have to do then you have to. So as you say there is no value for first comment.

Comment: This page in the docs might be useful for anyone coming across these comments: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html

Anyone is absolutely free to do what Abdulla has done - it's a great solution from someone who is no doubt extremely talented. However, I was merely attempting to point out that if you are to edit core files, there's a safer way to do it if you don't want to accidentally overwrite your edits when upgrading.